# Load .bmp file to Pascal

Tags: freepascal, bmp

I quite like encrypting and I have decided to encrypt .bmp file with some XOR code. But I am still struggling with loading .bmp to Pascal and I don´t know how to i.e read the header of bmp etc. Does anyone know how to do it?

I would appreciate all kind of tips :-) 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I did any serious Pascal programming, but I found the following wiki and information regarding graphics for you.  Take a look at the link below.

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Developing_with_Graphics

Comment: Thx, I will have a look at it. Meanwhile I have found another quite good source. I will try to get it on my own. If I had problems, I will ask. Thx :-)

Comment: You dont trully need a bmp loader function.